# Simple PHP inside HTML SELECT not working

Tags: php, html, forms, select

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
<label for="gender">Gender*: </label>
<select name="user[test]" id="gender">
<? echo "THISISATEST"?>
<option value="-1"> - Select - </option>
</select>
```

And it doesn't do anything.

However, this works fine:

```
<select name="user[test]" id="gender">
<option value="-1"> - Select - </option>
</select>
<? echo "THISISATEST"?>
```

What's going on?

Thanks!

Edit: I'm an idiot, I tried to simplify the problem for posting on here, turns out the echoing is appearing in the soruce and the line where I try to dynamically create the  just isn't working. Derp. I forgot to surround my shorthand if?else: with brackets, which caused the whole line not to echo.

Thanks

Comment: what is the purpose of doing this do you want to generate options through php?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you entirely certain short tags are enabled on your server? I'd just double check `<?php echo "THISISATEST"; ?>` and see if that improves your luck.  Also, did you view source - because that value may have been hidden on a rendered page when in a select as such.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="user[test]" id="gender">
    <? echo "THISISATEST"?> /// You can't echo string inside <select></select>
    <option value="-1"> - Select - </option>
</select>
```

Rather do

```
<select name="user[test]" id="gender">
    <option value="0"><? echo "THISISATEST"?></option>  // This will work
    <option value="1"> - Select - </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="user[test]" id="gender">
<option value="<?php
 echo "THISISATEST";
 ?>"><?php
 echo "THISISATEST";
 ?></option>  // This will work
<option value="1"> - Select - </option>
```

This should work fine. You can enter your desired value as well

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Your browser ignores text nodes under a `select` node. This arrangement is not in the HTML spec, so browsers are free to mutilate it however they like.